# Change destination viewController when editing is true or false

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, segue

I have a `viewController`with a `tableView`which contains all clubs, the user added. The user can reorder the `tableViewCells`with the `moverowat`function. If he selects a club, he comes to a `tableView`with all members from the club. Now I want to implement the ability, to get to another `viewController` where he can edit the content of the cell.

I have created this, but now it doesn't work:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableViewClub.isEditing == true{
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(EditClubViewController() as UIViewController, animated: true)}
        if tableViewClub.isEditing == false{
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MemberViewController() as UIViewController, animated: true)
        }
```

```swift
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if !tableViewClub.isEditing {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? MemberViewController,
             let selectedRow = self.tableViewClub.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
                return
        }

        destination.club = clubs[selectedRow]
        }}
```

When `tableView.isEditing`, then a `viewController` with a black background is shown. When `!tableView.isEditing`, this error is shown:`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I think it is because I have no storyboard segues. But is it possible, to have two segues from the `tableViewCell`? Or how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Interface Builder's segue. Instantiate the destination view controller manually so you can control which one you are transitioning to:

### Interface Builder

Select the `EditClubViewController` and give it a Storyboard ID. Do the same to `MemberViewController`.

[image]

### In code

In the first view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Turn this on so rows can be tapped during editing mode
    tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let destinationVC: UIViewController

    switch tableView.isEditing {
    case true:
        // If your storyboard isn't named "Main.storyboard" then put the actual name here
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editClubViewController") as! EditClubViewController
        // do your setup....
        destinationVC = vc
    case false:
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "memberViewController") as! MemberViewController
        // do your setup...
        destinationVC = vc
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
}
```